# Why wont my car start

Tags: battery, starting, chevrolet, astro

96 Chevy astro van
My blower motor resistor shorted out and I replaced it. a test says my battery and alternator are good. I can still jump start my car. but it wont start otherwise. if i jump the car but dont drive the car it will still start the next day.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like a bad battery to me ... how did you have it tested? If you just checked the voltage, that's not what's needed. You need to have a load test performed on it.

Comment: How old is the battery? If it's four years or older, I wouldn't fuss with it, and would just replace it.